# Python max function does not work within my own function / TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hey I am trying to print out the max (or min) of a list

The code in Python is the following:

```
def printDays(result):
    days=result[1]
    max=result[2]
    budget=result[3]
    if max==True: 
        cost=max(result[0])
    else:
        cost=min(result[0])
        
    template="You can spend $ {} in {} days with a $ {} limit"
    print(template.format(cost,days,budget))
```

"result" is a Tuple and "cost[0]" is a list with Integers (however they are all class types like  instead of just tuple - really just starting here and no idea if it makes a difference). I have checked so much with printing out the type.

I constantly get a
`TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`

pointing to the line:
`cost=max(result[0])`

Any idea why?

Comment: You assigned a `bool` value to `max`.

Comment: replace max with another variable in this line :max = result[2]

Comment: Because you redefined the built-in function max as variable. You cannot use it anymore as max function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have reinitialised the existing function max to `result[2]`. Anyways I've made your code a bit more pythonic.

```
def printDays(result):
  days, maximum, budget = result[1:4]
  if maximum: 
    cost=max(result[0])
  else:
    cost=min(result[0])
  #Better use a ternary. cost = max(result[0]) if maximum else min(result[0]) 
  template="You can spend $ {} in {} days with a $ {} limit"
  print(template.format(cost,days,budget))
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem because you assign `result[2]` to `max` and call `max`, you can change your code like below:

```
def printDays(result):
    days=result[1]
    max_min_checker = result[2]
    budget=result[3]
    if max_min_checker==True: 
        cost=max(result[0])
    else:
        cost=min(result[0])

    template="You can spend $ {} in {} days with a $ {} limit"
    print(template.format(cost,days,budget))
```